# The view could not be found in asp.net hybrd (Web forms and MVC) app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a Web forms app being converted to MVC so I set things up in Areas > Project2 > Views.  The MVC app I am bringing in used to have it's Views in the root level.

I created an registered the area like so:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Project2_home",
            "Project2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

I have in the structure setup like so:

```
Areas/Project2/Controllers/Home_Controller.cs
Areas/Project2/Models/etc.
Areas/Project2/Views/Home/ProjectDetails.cshtml
```

In the Home_Controller is the ProjectDetails action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}/{seId:int?}", Name = "ProjectDetails")]
    public ActionResult ProjectDetails(int id, int? seId)
    {    
        ViewBag.BackUrl = Request.Url.Query;
        Project estimatesProject = _projectRepository.GetProjectWithColumns(id);
        ViewBag.EstimatesProject = estimatesProject;

        if (seId.HasValue)
            return View(_projectRepository.GetProjectWithColumns(seId.Value));
        else
            return View(estimatesProject);
    }
```

If I put a code break atProjectDetails it runs through the action and gets the results then throws an exception when it cannot find:

```
View not found (~Views/Home/ProjectDetails)
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Views/Home/ProjectDetails` doesn't include `Areas/Project2/`. If you are going to use areas, you need to specify it

Comment: How do I specify it? I have a route set up for Home/Index.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-area-in-mvc-5/

Comment: The only thing different is my namespace doesn't have areas in it.

Comment: I have register all areas in Global.asax

Comment: did all this but still no luck